# Mocha: Approach to Testing instance of express.Router

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I've been designing a javascript controller file and I want to testing if the instance of my controller have a instance of the express's method `Router()`.

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {UF_Controller} from '../../controllers/uf.controller.js';

describe('UF Controller', UFControllerDescription);

function UFControllerDescription(){
    it('1. Should be have a express router instance', spec1);

    function spec1(){
        expect(UF_Controller.router).itself.to.respondTo('get');
        expect(UF_Controller.router).itself.to.respondTo('post');
        expect(UF_Controller.router).itself.to.respondTo('put');
        expect(UF_Controller.router).itself.to.respondTo('delete');
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
import express from 'express';
import { uf } from '../models/uf.model';

class UFController{

    constructor(){
        this.router = express.Router();
        this.router.get('/', this.getAll);
  }

    getAll(req, res, next){
        res.json(uf.todayUF());
    }

    getUF(req, res, next){
    }

    insertUF(req, res, next){
    }

    replaceUF(req, res, next){
    }

    updateUF(req, res, next){
    }

    deleteUF(req, res, next){
    }
}

export const UF_Controller = new UFController();
```

My question is:
**This is a valid way check an instance of the express router???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to duck-type Express router.

`express.Router` isn't a constructor and doesn't establish normal prototype chain that can be detected with `instanceof`. Instead, it [establishes prototype chain manually via hacky mixin technique](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.14.0/lib/router/index.js#L49-L50).

It can be tested with

```
expect(Object.getPrototypeOf(UF_Controller.router)).to.equal(express.Router);
```